# What's analog vs digital in music production?

Tags: production

What's the difference between analog and digital when it comes to music production? This might sound like a dumb question, but isn't everything that's connected to electricity digital?

Comment: Generally digital is processed through the use of computer coding/programming and analog is dependent on 'real' components such as capacitors, resistors , transistors, tapes and plates etc..

Comment: @jazzboy and yet most computer chips have billions of transistors..!

Comment: @topomorto yes but they still rely on programming :^)

Comment: "Isn't everything that's connected to electricity digital?" -- No. [Analog signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_signal) carry information by varying the voltage, while [digital signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal) carry information by encoding at discrete voltage levels.

Comment: As one of the best digital electronics design engineers I know will tell you,  "The world is analog."  Digital signals just create large thresholds intended to "weed out" noise.  If you don't pay attention to analog analysis, your digital electronics will fail.

Comment: If one of these answers seems to be a good explanation that makes sense to you, please accept it as the answer by clicking the check mark icon in the upper-left of the answer. If none of the answers is good enough to be accepted, perhaps edit your question and/or comment on one or more answer to explain what still isn't clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to answer in reverse order:

> but isn't everything that's connected to electricity digital?

Not even close. Most likely, all the lights in your house are analog. Your kitchen appliances could go either way, but if they are at least ten years old then they are probably 100% analog. The fan in your bathroom ceiling is probably analog.

Let's talk music stuff. The following pages list musical products that are electronic and also analog:

- Everything made by [Moog Music](https://www.moogmusic.com/products) except the apps and the Theremini is analog
- [Fender tube amps](https://shop.fender.com/en-US/guitar-amplifiers/vintage-pro-tube/) are analog
- Most [Ampeg](http://www.ampeg.com/products/) amps are all analog
- Everything made by [Fulltone](https://www.fulltone.com/pedals) is analog
- Scroll down the "Analog Synthesizers" on [Korg's product page](http://www.korg.com/us/products/synthesizers/) for a list of their analog products
- Sweetwater's web site lists [five pages of analog mixers](https://www.sweetwater.com/c264--Analog_Mixers) from various companies (some have digital effects sections that can be bypassed)
- Looks like all of [Manley Labs](https://www.manley.com/pro)' pro audio equipment is analog
- [Universal Audio](https://www.uaudio.com/hardware.html) has a page dedicated to their analog hardware

These are just a few examples. There are thousands upon thousands more analog musical products in the world.

> What's the difference between analog and digital when it comes to music production?

Analog electronic musical equipment creates and processes sound using various electrical voltages that are manipulated using electronic components. In case it's not clear, all acoustic instruments are analog, but they are not electronic.

Digital musical equipment either samples an analog electrical waveform and turns it into a stream of numbers, or it generates a stream of numbers that represent an electrical waveform. Software is then used to change ("process") the stream of numbers in ways that serve a musical purpose. Since our ears and speaker drivers are analog, at some point the stream of numbers is converted to an analog electrical waveform and run through one or more speaker or headphone drivers and it becomes sound that enter our ears and we hear music.

Digital computers are everywhere - you are using one to view this web page. Digital musical equipment are digital computers that are purpose built to generate and process musical information. Digital computers convert analog voltages to numbers, process those numbers, and then convert the numbers back into voltages (it's a little more complicated than that but let's leave it there for this question).

Analog musical equipment are [analog computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer) that process musical information. The voltages are processed directly, without being converted to numbers.

Comment: thanks, I really didnt understand the whole concept of analog vs digital. do people sometimes prefer analog over digital, like does it sound better to them in certain equipment?

Comment: oh wait, maybe since all speakers are analog them mb everything we hear is analog

Comment: "Most likely, all the lights in your house are analog" - I was wondering if a light that can only be on/off can be conceived of as digital!

Comment: @topomorto I suppose it could be, but that seems like a rather reductive view since that would suggest everything with an on/off switch could be viewed as being digital.

Comment: @foreyez Actual sound in the ear is always analog. The ear is a mechanical analog computer that decodes the intensities of different frequencies from a complex waveform. The different intensities create bands of pulse code modulated nerve impulses to the brain. One could argue that PCM nerve impulses are digital, but since they are not *clocked* (they are asynchronous), it's open to interpretation.

Comment: @foreyez Thinking about whether analog or digital is "better" misses the forest for the trees, IMHO. In many cases, it's not too hard to hear the difference between similar analog and digital systems, but neither type of technology is always inherently better. I find that digital technology works better in some ways and in some cases, while analog technology has other areas where it shines best. Obviously digital technology is often used to *imitate* analog technology, and so far there haven't been any perfect imitations. But digital technology does some things very well on its own.

Comment: @ToddWilcox You could indeed view an on/off switch itself as being able to represent a value 'digitally' - a binary digit (bit) is simply something that can *be* on or off.  Of course you wouldn't call a lawnmower 'digital' just because it *had* a switch.

Comment: @topomorto Agreed. I also wouldn't call a lamp digital just because it has a switch.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I've been asking these hardware related questions lately since I just got an OP-1. I'm in heaven right now..... :3

Comment: @ToddWilcox Of course you wouldn't in normal circumstances, but digital is to some extent a 'way of thinking' about what something represents. You might not consider your bedroom light 'digital' as you're normally not using it to represent information - but if you start using it to send Morse signals to your friend on the other side of the street, it becomes digital. I imagine you'd be happy to see the lamp driving your TOSLINK connections as digital (or if not inherently digital, at least, an element of a digital *system*).

Comment: @topomorto I disagree that Morse code is digital. There are analog multiplexers and analog coding schemes. Not all coding is inherently digital. My threshold for what counts as digital is that the signal must be converted to a sequence of *numbers* such that the code could be written in Arabic numerals. I would say modern algebra is digital but Greek geometric algebra is analog. It’s subtle but that’s how I view it.

Comment: I did wonder that too, but hey, I was already pushing it with the 'light bulb' thing! FWIW [this page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/science/ocr_gateway/home_energy/light_and_lasersrev1.shtml) opines that it is digital. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/39920/is-morse-code-binary-ternary-or-quinary is perhaps also relevant. If not digital, it certainly shares some strong similarities with digital though, in that it allows transmission of a number of specific discrete values.

Answer (score 6):

"Digital" means that at some stage in the recording process (if not all stages) an analog sound has been converted in a digital format, i.e. it has been sampled at a rate of 96 KHz (the normal rate these days; it used to be 44.1 KHz) and converted into "a long string of 0s and 1s". As most productions these days use computers, they are digital, as the computers use the digital format. "Analog" in this case means that the recording - of real instruments via microphones or direct injection - is to a physical tape recorder.

A comparison from the world of photography: all pictures taken by a smart phone or a digital camera are digital - that's why we are always told how many megapixels there are. A picture taken using film is analog - it is not sampled and converted. Theoretically this means that a filmed picture has infinite resolution; one can enlarge a filmed picture to any extent and always see a definite picture, whereas a digital picture will at some stage appear to be a sequence of dots.

With regard to music, it is much easier to manipulate digital recordings, but they have a definite resolution; the higher the sampling rate, the better the sound - or conversely, the lower the sampling rate, the worse the sound.

Also, the equipment used (primarily the "ADC", analogue to digital converter) plays a large part in the quality of the conversion. Compare the original version of an analogue record transferred to CD as opposed the a remixed version of the same record, or a record recorded with a 100% digital path.

Read about the Nyquist frequency, which explains the sampling rate.

Comment: so the only analog in music production is when recording to a physical tape? if that's the case then 99.9% of audio equipment is digital right? (since noone uses tape anymore). If there's some kind of equipment that's still in use today that uses analog and is important pls let me know.

Comment: Today I read somewhere (possibly in reply to another question on this forum) that major artists are returning to analog recording.

Comment: @foreyez 'if that's the case then 99.9% of audio equipment is digital right?' - I think in the spirit in which you meant that question, that's right. Though ultimately the audio has to be converted back to analogue for use to be able to hear it. Speakers are (simplistically speaking) always analogue.

Comment: See this question and its answer: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/did-hardware-generally-move-to-software-for-music-production

Comment: Definitely edit out the wildly inaccurate sample rate statement at the very beginning. The SHARC II processors that seem to be used in every digital musical device these days seem to always sample at 96 kHz. All the Strymon and Line 6 stuff is now running at 96 kHz, along with most digital mixers and seems like everything else. I’m not sure if you can stilll buy and interface that won’t handle at least 96 kHz any more.

Comment: Also film cameras do not even come close to having infinite resolution, not even theoretically. The resolution of camera film is determined by the size of the silver grains in the chemical emulsion, which depends on the sensitivity (ISO) of the film. The more sensitive the film, the higher the ISO number and the larger the grains are. That's why you can't blow up 1200 speed film to 8x10 without it looking very grainy.

Comment: @foreyez As you'll see in my answer, there is a lot more going on in music that is analog besides tape. A large number of big-budget recordings are actually mixed with analog consoles and effects. The frontier in mixing consoles right now is analog consoles that are digitally controlled, so you can record the console moves and automation into the digital recording, but the actual processing of the audio is 100% analog.

Comment: @No'amNewman Major artists and recording studios are not generally *returning* to analog, many of them never left it.

Comment: @foreyez No.  Cassette tapes are analog, but computer backup tapes are digital.  Recording studio tapes could be analog or digital, depending on the equipment used.  Vinyl records are analog.  Compact discs are digital.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, an explanation of the difference between analogue in digital in general terms. I ask you "How tall is your cat?"...

If you hold out your hands and say "it's this big"...
[image: "How tall is your cat?"]

...that's an **analogue** way of conveying the information.

If you say "He's 28 cm high", that's a **digital** way of conveying the information. The actual physical amount has been represented as a **number**. (Note that the word digit means (a single) number - though we tend to use the term 'digital' to mean numbers represented in binary form).

The way analogue audio signals are converted to digital data streams is shown in [this slide](https://www.slideshare.net/SehrishRafiq1/lecture-09-14435826):

[image]

The audio data is sampled, then converted into (typically) a [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) bitstream that represents the waveform.

The main advantages and disadvantages of analogue and digital can still be seen by our cat-measuring analogy. If I want to actually *record* what the person showed me with their hands without using numbers (analogue), it's quite difficult to do - I might draw a line on a piece of paper that's the same size, but I'd probably make a small mistake. Then when I show someone else (with my hands) how big the cat is, I might make another mistake. And this is the problem with analogue - it's hard to keep copying the data accurately. With analogue audio, the 'height' (of the audio waveform) may be stored as magnetic patterns on a tape - but as you can imagine, if you keep copying the sound from one tape to another, you'll get distortion and noise.

If, on the other hand, I have the measurement digitally, things are much easier - I can write the number down, remember it, and copy that same number lots of times without it degrading. And that's one of the huge advantages of digital information - it can be stored and copied much more easily without introducing errors in doing so.

What's the disadvantage of digital, then? Well, we can probably guess that the cat wasn't *exactly* 28cm high - the 28 was a measurement made to a limited degree of resolution. We always have to make a choice, when we measure things, with how much resolution we want to do so - we can say 28, or 27.8, or 27.79... but we have to stop somewhere. Real-world digital systems *do* have a limited level of resolution - it's are limited by the bit depth of the system (and, in the time dimension, by the sample rate). However, well-designed digital systems these days are can store information to such a high degree of resolution that this fundamental limitation in how actually causes fewer problems than the noise and inaccuracies generated in analogue systems. They also have advantages of being able to store a lot more audio information in a smaller physical space, and these days, usually being a lot cheaper.

So, now that these very accurate digital systems are available, why would anyone still use an analogue system for recording and processing?

There are some reasons...

- **Avoiding latency.** conversion between analogue and digital can be done quickly, but not instantaneously. If you need a super-immediate realtime system, analogue may be preferable,
- **'Warmth'.** Some of the small distortions imparted by analogue systems can be subjectively pleasant...
- **Tolerance**. ... while distortions added in digital systems are typically unpleasant. Specifically, we tend to try to avoid recording at too high a level on a digital system, as the way it clips the waveforms off square at the top sounds nasty. *Some* (not all) analogue systems are more gentle.
- **Physicality** - It's fun to manipulate a tape or record with your hands. It doesn't work with digital - the electronics just get confused.

But for most use cases, these aren't enough to beat digital's practicality. Which is why the vast majority of audio recording and processing equipment being sold today is digital.

Oh, and....

> isn't everything that's connected to electricity digital?

No. You have to ask yourself if it is somehow storing or transmitting values, and representing them as *specific numbers* when it does so. If it's doing that, it's digital.

<sub>* yes, it also means 'finger'... those things on our hands we use to count with!</sub>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75941/discussion-between-topo-morto-and-todd-wilcox).

Comment: Note, you left "precise" in the second to last sentence, which is unnecessary, but I've retracted my down vote. Regarding "warmth", you could add that some small distortions added in digital systems can be *un*pleasant. So it's a win-win to go analog in terms of sound quality. It's mainly the price/performance ratio of digital that makes it so popular.

Comment: @ToddWilcox yep, added that good point in there.